# How do I test a redirect in sinatra using rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, padrino

I'm trying to test for a redirect on the homepage in my sinatra app (more specifically, a padrino app), in rspec. I've found `redirect_to`, however it seems to be in rspec-rails only. How do you test for it in sinatra?

So basically, I'd like something like this:

```
  it "Homepage should redirect to locations#index" do
    get "/"
    last_response.should be_redirect   # This works, but I want it to be more specific
    # last_response.should redirect_to('/locations') # Only works for rspec-rails
  end
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this (not tested):

```
it "Homepage should redirect to locations#index" do
  get "/"
  last_response.should be_redirect   # This works, but I want it to be more specific
  follow_redirect!
  last_request.url.should == 'http://example.org/locations'
end
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: Failure/Error: follow_redirect!
     Sequel::DatabaseError:
       SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: locations
. I'm guessing it is a database issue though. Will need to look into this further...

Comment: can you tell me where those `last_request`, `last_response` methods are documented... How are you able to call methods like `url` on those. I am new, so couldn't get it.

Comment: @ArupRakshit See http://www.rubydoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/master/Rack/Test/Methods for documentation of last_request/last_response.

Comment: @SteveMidgley Thanks for your reply.. Any help on this [problem](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rspec/WX-7KRK_EQY) ?

Comment: Can also do something like `expect(last_response.location).to eq('http://example.org/locations')` without having to follow the redirect.

Answer (score 17):

More directly you can just use last_response.location.

```
it "Homepage should redirect to locations#index" do
  get "/"
  last_response.should be_redirect
  last_response.location.should include '/locations'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In the new `expect` syntax it should be:

```
it "Homepage should redirect to locations#index" do
  get "/"
  expect(last_response).to be_redirect   # This works, but I want it to be more specific
  follow_redirect!
  expect(last_request.url).to eql 'http://example.org/locations'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

## March 2024 update:

```ruby
it 'redirects to the root page' do
  get '/'
  expect(last_response).to be_redirect
  expect(URI(last_response.location).path).to eql '/locations'
end
```

- Most of the time we are only interested in the correct path while the default host of `example.org` comes from `Rack::Test` and it should not be duplicated in the test.
- `follow_redirect!` is not needed since we can take the new URL from the `Location` header.